# Incorrect padding error with Google oAuth2 and Youtube API

Tags: python, django, youtube-api, google-oauth, padding

I've been trying to authenticate my django (python 3.4, django 1.9) app with google oAuth2.0 to use the Youtube Data API v3.

I have a JSON key for server to server authentication (type: service account).

The error originates from the build() method below:

```
client_email = '***@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
with open('key.json', 'r+b', 0) as f:
    private_key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube')
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

service = build(str('youtube', 'v3', http=http_auth)
response = service.channels().list(part="id").execute()
```

The error I get is:

Incorrect padding exception at
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py in importKey, line 660

which is this line:

```
der = binascii.a2b_base64(b('').join(lines[1:-1]))
```

I'm new to python and django, so my debugging skills are not up to par yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to this question but I found out that you cannot use service accounts with YouTube Data API v3, which makes this a moot question.

source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication